# CPU L1/L2 cache size over the years

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I'm trying to find a graph with information on the CPU L1/L2 cache sizes over the years.

I have only succeeded to find an old chart from 2008 ([here](https://images.anandtech.com/reviews/cpu/intel/nehalem/part3/cachepercore.png)).

I know that the cache sizes have stayed roughly the same over the past twenty years, I just want a graphical representation of this info.

Does anyone know where to find one?

Thanks!

Comment: For what architectures?  Just Intel?  Keep in mind that around 2008 was when Intel started using 3 levels of cache, so their L2 has been per-core private 256kiB for a long time (until very recently when they bumped it up in Skylake-X, and then also in client chips like Ice Lake, and then Alder Lake is another story with a mix of Performance and Efficiency cores, the latter having groups of cores sharing an L2.)  So if you actually mean last-level cache, that's not L2 these days, on modern x86.  But on some ARM CPUs it still is.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment @PeterCordes. Actually I meant the private CPU core cache (not the LLC), and I don't really care for any specific architecture. I admit that I did not know that Alder Lake shares the L2 across cores (that compilates things a bit), thanks for that!

Comment: https://www.anandtech.com/show/16881/a-deep-dive-into-intels-alder-lake-microarchitectures/4 has some details on Alder Lake.  Note that AMD Bulldozer-family did weird stuff with a pair of integer cores sharing a SIMD unit and some cache. https://www.realworldtech.com/bulldozer/3/.  It was an attempt to do something other than one wide core with SMT, with different tradeoffs.  Also note Bulldozer-family's write-through L1d with only a 4kiB write-combining buffer, so write-intensive microbenchmarks bottleneck on that working-set size, not L1d size.

Comment: https://www.7-cpu.com/ has full details on cache hierarchies for the microarchitectures it covers, including some ARM, POWER, SPARC, MIPS, and Itanium, as well as x86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is apparently an open database of historical CPU specifications at http://cpudb.stanford.edu/. I don't see the specific visualization you are asking for, but the data contains cache sizes for processors spanning from 1970s to 2016, so it might be possible to create your own plot from it.

Comment: That doesn't seem to show cache numbers for many microarchitectures. e.g. Skylake just shows `0` in that column for all models: http://cpudb.stanford.edu/manufacturers/9/code_names/155.  And since there's only one column, that's probably showing last-level cache, which isn't L2 on Intel since Nehalem.  e.g. the AMD K10 table which does have non-zero sizes (http://cpudb.stanford.edu/manufacturers/1/microarchitectures/1) shows 2048, 4096, or 6144 for the models it lists.  Probably total L2 size, nothing about L1d size.  Still maybe marginally useful, but without core counts it's harder to use.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Actually this DB seems to have data regarding L1 and L2 cache sizes (from the DB's raw data). It is a bit incomplete, but a much better solution than scraping Wikipedia... Thanks @ChristophBurschka!

Comment: Just for reference from a computer I built in 2013 AMD FX-8320 Eight-Core(integer cores) Piledriver; Technology: 32nm 4 cores (8 threads); L1instruction Size: 64KBx4 (256KB Total) ; L1data Size: 16KBx8 (128KB Total); L2 Size: 2MB (8MB Total); L3 Size: 8MB